# accessing files in another apps directory

Tags: android

I am hoping to develop an application that needs to read a log file from another popular application. The log file is in /android/data/com.xxx.xxx/files.

Initially I thought my application would need root, but using two different file managers on an unrooted phone, I can access the /Android/data/com.xxx.xxx/Files/ directory and read/write the files there.

Everything I read online tells me it shouldn't work that way though. Can someone help clarify things?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is with the `FileProvider`. Here a good example on how to implement this:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Remember to add these two lines in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to have the permission to read the files from other dirs.

Comment: Sorry.. It was a problem on the copy paste. Here the two permissions to include in your manifest file: uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: You don't need those permissions if you're not writing/reading to/from sdcard i.e. external memory.

Answer (score 0):

To read this path:
  "/your_sd_path/android/data/com.xxx.xxx/"
As you tested, root acess is not needed.

But for reading app dir in below path:
  "/data/app/com.xxx.xxx/"
You should have root acess.

Hope it helps